# SSH config: setting initial directory after login

Tags: ssh

Is it possible, for each host, to set initial directory where shell would cd into when logged in? (not home)

For example, I have a snippet in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host mybusiness
Hostname mybusines.com
User plone
```

And now I can ssh to this host with `ssh mybusiness` command, but always the first task I need to do is to type in the command `cd /srv/www`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, but you could config your shell's init script at the server. If you use bash at the server, you could add this line to the end of `~/.bashrc` at the server:

```
cd /my/initial/dir
```

---

Another option is to create a small script on your client for starting SSH-connections, which will run a remote command after login:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is the file "/home/myuser/bin/myssh":
ssh $1 "cd /my/initial/dir"
```

Run it like this:

```
# myssh mybusiness
```

Comment: Looks like there is no way around this without creating your own helper scripts :( I'll mark this as correct answer.